# polytree forest

Tags: java, graph, jung

I have an oriented graph on my hard drive, and I think it may be a forest of polytree.

- I would like to create independent partitions of connected vertex.
- I would like to confirm that each partition is a polytree, and to find the roots.

Can JUNG do it for me ? 
Have you another java graph library to suggest ?

Comment: Wouldn't the best place to look for this information be whatever process put the graph there? I mean, it's not like they grow on trees! (Well, they kind of are trees, but you know what I mean!)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no information on the process that generated graph. I'm performing data mining here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WeakComponentClusterer will divide the graph into connected components.

The library does not include a method to check whether something is a polytree.  But it shouldn't be hard for you to whip up some code that uses the JUNG API to do it.

Comment: I performed a depth-first search to classify edges in two categories: tree edges and back edges. The graph component is a tree when there is not back edge.